# What is the space that lack a charge density?

Tags: electrostatics

In the section 1.7 Poisson and Laplace equations in the book of classical electrodynamics 3rd ed. for J. D. Jackson, it has been mentioned, that in regions of space that lack a charge density, the scalar potential satisfies the Laplace equation:
∇^2 Φ=0
so my question, is this equation must simply means Φ=0, due to the note of free charge density, or ρ(x)=0.

[image]

I hope that this question does not seem ridiculous. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not just the zero solution that satisfies the poisson equation. Any constant value does as well as any linear field gradient.

Comment: Thank you Paul, but I am sorry, I still stuck with the equation of scalar potential, if the ρ(x)=0 in the space that lack a charge density, then Φ(x)=0.

Comment: @AdilNajim Paul's point was: try to see whether $\Phi(x) = A$ or $\Phi(x) = Bx$ (with $A$ and $B$ constant values) satisfy the Poisson's equation. You'll see that they do, and hence are perfectly valid potentials in the absence of a charge density.

Answer (score 0):

No,
Do read about laplace equation, from any standard textbook of partial differential equations, and you will get that.